# Disambiguation of 'free' tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow

The tag 'free' on stackoverflow is used with very different semantics:

- The Standard C `free()` function to deallocate memory
- Free software, books, ...
- Other uses I may have overlooked

What is the procedure to disambugate these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change tags for the second usage of `free` to `free-as-in-beer`. ;)

On a more serious note, we *could* start employing a [`gratis`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis) tag to cover the second case, but how many users are actually going to use it, or search for it, or even understand it? The tag `free` is a more natural tag to use, and yes, this means that there will be some ambiguity because there are other meanings (like the `free()` function, etc.).

I don't know that there is any good way or pressing need to disambiguate the different uses. Users can just focus on the question title or the other 4 (potential) tags on the question to figure out which `free` the question is about.

Comment: The only issue with leaving it ambiguous is what to write in the tag wiki. That feature increases the importance of getting tags down to single meanings. 'Course, I don't intend to write that wiki, so it's all the same to me.

Comment: @dmckee: I guess you could just add both uses to the tag wiki.