# Suggest disambiguation to user when tagging

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ambiguous-tags

**Minor/Moderate Problem**:

From my minimal time here, it appears that there are several tags: [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) [free](/questions/tagged/free) [at](/questions/tagged/at) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [as](/questions/tagged/as) [sts](/questions/tagged/sts) [create](/questions/tagged/create) [document](/questions/tagged/document), and a *few* others tagged as [ambiguous-tags](/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags)[on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags), which *might* have an ambiguous meaning.

- [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99898/) talks about the ambiguities of [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) - [Job Control Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language), [Jakarta Commons Logging](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/ctrb_classload_jcl.html), Java Constraints Library, JEDI Code Library
- [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87381) talks about the ambiguities of [free](/questions/tagged/free) - free() as in malloc(), free as in beer, etc.
- [at](/questions/tagged/at) as in the linux scheduler, the windows scheduler, [and many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT)
- [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) - as in [the framework](http://www.microsoft.com/net/) or [the internet <- mistagging on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[.net]+%2Binternet+-framework)
- [xp](/questions/tagged/xp) - Windows XP, Extreme Programming, etc.
- [jwt](/questions/tagged/jwt) -  JSON Web Token  or Java Web Toolkit

Certain tags can, especially by new users, be misinterpreted.  Some, especially the acronyms, have several relevant meanings.

**Possible Solution #1:** When tags are added to a question, there is already a tag suggestion feature (which I can't seem to capture via Shutter.  drat.).

When you type in "jcl" into the tags you only see [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl).  Could this list be augmented to include a list of **possible ambiguities**.  Similar in purpose to the [Wikipedia Disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Disambiguation) feature, we could provide:

[.net](/questions/tagged/.net) <- This one grayed out

---

*Possible Ambiguity*, please select from the following tags to be more specific

[.net](/questions/tagged/.net) - a software framework for the Microsoft Windows operating system...

[internet](/questions/tagged/internet) - Global system of interconnected computer networks serving billions of users worldwide...

**Possible Solution #2:** or perhaps something much less dramatic, just including these ambiguities in the tag auto-completed options:

User types in "net" and sees:

[.net](/questions/tagged/.net)

[internet](/questions/tagged/internet)

even though the word "internet" doesn't start with 'net'.

Comment: I like the first one, we've wanted that on UL for some ambiguous tags (for example, [cd] can refer to the command or the disc)

Comment: Worth noting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor

Comment: @Robert, Yep!  Can't wait for the devs to mark this question as [status-completed].  But I'm using this as a repository of ambiguous tags in the mean time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe we could add a new thing to the Tag Wiki for the tag dropdown, call it `Tag Hint`, and it could show a very short tagging info piece, like so:

[image: Tag Hint Example]

This would really help, since most users don't hover over the tag for the tag excerpt instructions before they post.

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  And for the record, I tried three different ways to get a screen shot of that feature.  Were you using Windows?  (I've been in Ubuntu.)

Comment: I use [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/) I've found it to be the best, and it has a great editor.