# Tag creation request +[bank] +[conflict] => [bank-conflict]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, tag-creation

I don't have 1500 rep on Stack overflow.  But I would like to create a tag "bank-conflict" to deal specifically with the memory issues related to nvidia graphics cards, known as bank conflicts.

At present the tags [bank](/questions/tagged/bank) and [conflict](/questions/tagged/conflict) appear to be a mess.  Could someone create the [bank-conflict](/questions/tagged/bank-conflict) tag so that then I can add it to these questions & remove [bank](/questions/tagged/bank) and [conflict](/questions/tagged/conflict)?

[Why aren't there bank conflicts in global memory for cuda/opencl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843032/why-arent-there-bank-conflicts-in-global-memory-for-cuda-opencl)

[What is a bank conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841877/what-is-a-bank-conflict-doing-cuda-opencl-programming)

And also add it to some of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bcuda+%2Bbank+%2Bconflict)?

**Edit:** To provide a bit more information:

The phrase "bank conflict" is a [term used by nVidia](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=64499) in their documentation.  If you look at [bank](/questions/tagged/bank) it has several questions about finance and one about reflective angles.  If you look at [conflicts](/questions/tagged/conflicts), most deal with source code merging *conflicts*.  I'm [just trying to minimize ambiguities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100070).

Comment: Tag created. You should probably keep the bank tag, though. It has a sensible use in the realm of finance. But this effort to clean up tags is good; keep up the good work.

Comment: Yes.  I wasn't suggesting to eliminate the tags.  Only to remove them from *those two* questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cody created the tag.  He retagged the above questions.  I retagged a few others which were specifically questions about bank-conflicts in shared memory on a GPU.  I'll submit a tag wiki later today.